# SQL INSERT INTO - Duplicates still exist (How to modify insert into?)

Tags: python, sql, database, insert, mariadb

I have 3 MariaDB-SQL tables and I want to insert some data:

---

**Restaurant**

- ID_Restaurant (Primary Key, Auto Increment)
- RestaurantName
- Location

**Restaurant_has_Request**

- ID_Restaurant(Foreign Key)
- ID_Request (Foreign Key)

**Request**

- ID_Request (Primary Key, Auto Increment)
- Date
- Adults

---

One Restaurant has 0 or infinity Requests. One Request can have 1 or infinity Restaurants.

I am iterating through a request site for only one Request. That means I want to treat first one Request and then I save the related one or more Restaurants. After I have done this another Request will be treated and so on.

I have the following Python Code for inserting the data:

```
cursor.execute('insert into Restaurant(RestaurantName, Location) values(%s, %s)',(RestaurantName, Location))

# ID from last insert
ID_Restaurant_Cache = cursor.lastrowid

cursor.execute('insert into Request(Date, Adults) values(%s, %s)',(Date, Adults))

# ID from last insert
ID_Request_Cache = cursor.lastrowid

cursor.execute('insert into Restaurant_has_Request(ID_Restaurant, ID_Request) values(%s, %s)',(ID_Restaurant_Cache, ID_Request_Cache))
```

The problem is that I have still duplicates... How can I modify the Python code that I use the existing entry from a Restaurant, when it already exists (RestaurantName & Location is already in the database)?
I have also duplicates for the Request. I want to use the same Request ID for one iteration and then I want to use another Request ID.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the restaurant already exists before inserting.

```
cursor.execute('select ID_Restaurant from Restaurant where RestaurantName = %s', (RestaurantName,))
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    ID_Restaurant_Cache = row[0]
else:
    cursor.execute('insert into Restaurant(RestaurantName, Location) values(%s, %s)',(RestaurantName, Location))
    ID_Restaurant_Cache = cursor.lastrowid
```

You should also add a unique index on the `RestaurantName` column, to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Shouldn't `Restaurant_has_Request` have

```
PRIMARY KEY(ID_restaurant, ID_request),
INDEX(ID_request, ID_restaurant)
```